# Keeping a randomly chosen variable static in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am *very* new to Javascript so excuse me if I am using the incorrect terminology.

For my class, I have to create a game where the user has to guess which letter the computer is "thinking."

What I am struggling with is how to get the "computer" to choose ONE letter from the array and keeping it static rather than choosing a new letter each time the user makes a guess.  Here is my code-

```
 var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];



document.onkeyup = function() {
    var userguess = 
        String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    console.log(userguess);


 var computerGuess = 
     alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)]
 console.log(computerGuess);

 }
```

Comment: Simply move your `computerGuess` variable declaration outside of your `keyup` event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your `computerGuess`outside the event handler. You're generating a new value on each `keyup`:

```js
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

var computerGuess = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];

document.onkeyup = function() {
  var userguess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
  
  console.log(`userguess: ${userguess}, computerGuess: ${computerGuess}`);
}
```